# How to Disable Spell Checking for All My Projects

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to disable spell check at the IDE level in PHPStorm?  I need to individually disable spell check for all my projects right now which is a bit of a pest.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

There is no "global" setting for existing projects -- it needs to be done for **each project individually** (Spell Checker is an inspection and Inspections are configured on per-project level).

You need to disable whole group at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Proofreading` (used to be `Spelling` before).

***P.S.** Sure, you could use IDE-wide Inspections profile instead of Project level one... but in reality you will not be using it: each project has different requirements (different tech stack used / different versions etc etc)*

[image]

---

You can configure it to be disabled by default for **any future new projects** at `File | New Projects Setup | Settings for New Projects...` (previously was named as `File | Default Settings`).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.2/configure-project-settings.html#new-default-settings

[image]

---

Also check suggestion by @Amged -- edit your Color Scheme to simply remove any visual effects for misspelt words: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General --> Errors & Warnings | Typo`.

This way it will affect ALL projects straight away as long you use that Color Schema. It will also allow you to still list all typos if you run `Code | Inspect Code...`.

The possible down-side: spell checker still runs; you will see extra 2 menu entries when right clicking on such words.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's been silently bugging me for *years*, and your answer just solved my problem. Too bad SE doesn't have a tipjar. Hunt me down and email me and I'll give me you a tip anyway ;-)

Comment: Thanks again, @LazyOne! Just to update this, I've filled a bug in Youtrack which is still unresolved: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24663

Answer (score 26):

You could leave the Spell Checking inspection enabled and just remove the visual effect in the editor by going to Settings | Colors & Fonts | General | Typo and unchecking Effect. This way it will not highlight the typos in the editor but when you manually run the code inspector the typos are listed.

Comment: Me too, since I've got Spelling inspection unchecked in the Default Settings, but it still gets applied every time to new projects. This seems to be the only real solution for now.

Answer (score 9):

I'm working with "CLion" but I'm pretty sure the settings are pretty much close to "phpstorm" as both of them are produced by the same company :)

Go to the `File` tab and then select settings.
In the opened window select the items as the picture below and uncheck the spelling item.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

windows:**File->Settings->Editor** Now click **Inspections** item and find **Spelling** click check button and now **apply and ok**

Answer (score 0):

To change it globally in the `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections` change `Project default` to `Default.`