# How to ignore spelling errors in comments - PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm show yellow lines below Turkish words.

How can I ignore all spelling errors in comments.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983942/how-to-disable-spell-checking-for-all-my-projects

Comment: @Raptor *"use another IDE"* -- good idea. Let me make another suggestion: "your kid behaves bad" -- make another one; or "your car is out of fuel -- buy another one".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Inspections | Spelling | Typo`**

You can configure this inspection to ignore comments.

[image]

---

But **ideally** I would recommend adding dictionary for that language so IDE can check for spelling mistakes: `Settings | Spelling | Dictionaries tab`

Dictionary file is a plain-text UTF-8 encoded file with 1 word per line.

Comment: How to reload dictionary? I made correction in dictionary file and after restart phpstorm it still underlines corrected words, even when I change dictionary file name and add that new file in settings and remove old dictionary file.

Comment: @Sruj What dictionary? What kind of changes those were? Ideally you do not need to touch any bundled dictionaries. All words should be in lower case and files should be in UTF-8 with no BOM.