# How to disable spell checking for specific file?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm ok with PhpStorm spell checking overall in my project, But one of my files has a lot of arbitrary words, Is it possible to disable it in specific files ? (windows 10)

Comment: See this one first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14984416/783119 Then just: 1) create a custom scope that will include such undesired files. 2) Configure that Typo inspection/whole Spellchecking section to be disabled for that custom scope.

Comment: Also, you may add the "/** @noinspection SpellCheckingInspection */" in the PHP file beginning (right after the <?php tag).