# PhpStorm: how to Make the inspector / debugger ignore stuff in comments?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, spell-checking

I don't need it telling me I spelled the word "danggit!" incorrectly. I just want it to ignore the comments.

like this:

```
<?php
 $a = 123;// simple as, danggit!
    /* danggit, this frustrates me! */
```

also

```
"The word 'thru' is informal. Consider replacing it with through."
```

I dont want to see this, especially in comments

Comment: Where specifically? Is it about your code only .. or VCS commit window etc? Be more specific please.

Comment: But speaking in general: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/14984416/783119 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/spellchecking.html , in particular: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/spellchecking.html#configure-the-typo-inspection -- you can configure the `Typo` inspection to ignore comments in your code.

Comment: Thanks, the last link solved it for me.  settings>Editor>Inspections>Proofreading >Typo>options  uncheck 'process comments'

Comment: Danggit, now i'm getting "The word 'thru' is informal. Consider replacing it with through."  I dont want to see this, especially in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need it telling me I spelled the word "danggit!" incorrectly. I just want it to ignore the comments.

You can configure where this "Typo" inspection should be applied at the following screen: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Proofreading | Typo`.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/spellchecking.html#configure-the-typo-inspection

[image]

> Danggit, now i'm getting "The word 'thru' is informal. Consider replacing it with through." I dont want to see this, especially in comments.

This is a different thing in action. This time it's **Grammar**.

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Natural Languages | Grammar and Style` -- Here on a `Scopes` tab you can configure the same. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/grammar.html#scope

[image]

... or/and configure what rules to use (on a `Rules` tab): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/grammar.html#rules

[image]

In case if you need to configure too many of them, well... just disable the Grammar checks completely: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Proofreading | Grammar`

[image]